# Create multiple instances of beans during method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javabeans, cdi

During a method, I may need to spawn a download bean to fetch a file.  As I receive these calls in parallel, I only want to download the file once.  I don't know the right way to express the following pseudocode in JEE/CDI:

```
if (download_required) {
    monitor.enter();
    if (!map.ContainsKey(downloadPath))
    {
        //CDI inject new instance of downloader here.

        downloader.File = downloadPath;
        downloader.startDownload();
        map.put(downloadPath, downloader);
        monitor.exit();
        downloader.waitForDownload();
    } else {
        monitor.exit();
        map.get(downloadPath).waitForDownload();
    }
}
```

I want to use CDI as I need to set properties on the downloader from JNDI variables.  Each downloader is responsible for downloading a file and leaving some state.  Note that each downloader will be given a different state and therefore must be a new instance of the bean.

Just before I give up on CDI, inject the variables into the parent class and then use standard java with some static's to instantiate the above, is there a "correct" way to achieve this with CDI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java EE7, you could use `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance`:

```
@Inject Instance<Download> downloadProvider;

public void yourMethod() {
    Download download = downloadProvider.get();
    try {
        // do something with your download instance
    } finally {
        downloadProvider.destroy(download);
    }
}
```

Your download bean must be in `@Dependent` scope.

Comment: So the Instance<> is guaranteed to be a new instance each time, and will stay in scope until a given method is finished with it?